# Is it okay to put fonts and it's related css in the public directory, and preloading them using a `<link />` element?

Tags: css, vue.js, fonts, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to optimize the use of fonts in my Nuxt 3 application. Nuxt 3 documentations suggest to put the fonts in the `assets` directory, but I wanted to preload the fonts for better performance, so I've added them and the css file that defines my `font-face`s to the `public` directory, and added them to my project via `app.vue` file like this

`app.vue`

```html
<template>
  <Head>
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="/fonts/font.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </Head>
  <nuxt-layout>
    <nuxt-page />
  </nuxt-layout>
</template>
```

Here is my `font.css` file which is placed in the `~/public/fonts` directory, next to my font files:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Urbanist";
  src: url("/fonts/Urbanist/Urbanist[wght].woff2") format('woff2'),
    url("/fonts/Urbanist/Urbanist[wght].ttf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.woff2") format('woff2'),
    url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.ttf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff2") format('woff2'),
    url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.woff2") format('woff2'),
    url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.woff2") format('woff2'),
    url("/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.ttf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Everything is working fine, but I wanted to know if it's the right approach?
Is there a better way to preload my fonts for better performance?

Comment: You're asking for opinionated advice, which is *off-topic* on [SO]. Questions here should focus on facts, rather than opinions. In other words, you can ask how to make something work, or what's wrong with your code, but you can't ask which of two ways to achieve the same is better, as the answers to the second question tend to be opinionated. To make your question objective, you first have to exactly define the full list of criteria, each with its own weight in the "better" equation. Because for another developer or team they will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't really get anything else from loading it from the public directory or the assets one regarding preloading. You may have some optimizations in the `assets` one but anyway, preloading a local font is probably not useful and can even make your performance page speed worse (because of your page's loading order).
Give a read to that one: https://web.dev/font-best-practices/#be-cautious-when-using-preload-to-load-fonts

Here is a thread on how to optimize fonts even further: https://twitter.com/filrakowski/status/1582691561741070336
There you will see tools from [Meownica](https://meowni.ca/font-style-matcher/) and [Daniel](https://github.com/unjs/fontaine) that could be useful.
Font optimization is a broad topic and I'll recommend following the good practices recommended by experts, on top of using those tools.

Want to go even further? Here [you go](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/01/front-end-performance-2021-free-pdf-checklist/).

---

TLDR: follow the recommendations.